# Lotus 1-2-3 and Microsoft Flight Simulator as unofficial compatibility benchmark?

Tags: ibm-pc, compatibility

Do I remember correctly about an unofficial but popular test of "PC compatibility" in the early 1980s? Basically if a machine could run vanilla versions of both Lotus 1-2-3 and Microsoft Flight Simulator, reviewers at the time would declare it as "PC Compatible".  (Note that back then, customized versions of popular software were often available on well-regarded machines.) One particular memory is that the [DEC Rainbow 100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_100) computer, while superior to clones in almost every aspect, failed this particular benchmark and was deemed by the computer press as inadequate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, I think you did. E.g. from [The Digital Antiquarian](https://www.filfre.net/tag/compaq/):

> Having quickly concluded that simply copying IBM’s ROMs wasn’t a wise option, Compaq hired a staff of fifteen programmers who would dedicate the months to come to creating a slavish imitation. ... Instead of relying on IBM’s published BIOS specifications ... the team took the thirty biggest applications on the market and worked through them one at a time, analyzing each BIOS call each program made and figuring out through trial and error what response it needed to receive. The two trickiest programs, which would go on to become a sort of stress test for clone compatibility both inside and outside of Compaq, proved to be *Lotus 1-2-3* and *Microsoft Flight Simulator*.

Comment: Other instances include the marketing materials for the Olivetti M-24 ([AT&T 6300](https://sites.google.com/site/att6300shrine/Home) in the US) which specifically mentioned its compatibility with Lotus 1-2-3 and Microsoft Flight Simulator (see also [its review in Creative Computing](https://archive.org/details/creativecomputing-1985-06/page/n33/mode/2up)). It was common at the time for reviewers to test new PCs with the programs they used; see [this BYTE review of the PC1512 and Xen-i](https://archive.org/details/byte-magazine-1987-02/page/n325/mode/2up).

Comment: I was quite fond of my DEC Rainbow.  But it was a long time before you could run LOTUS 1-2-3 on it.  Some pretty good free software for it, if you knew where to look.